# Determining the Lie algebra of a matrix Lie group

Tags: matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I have the following Lie group:

$$G:=\bigg\{\begin{pmatrix} x&0\\y &1/x\end{pmatrix}\bigg\vert x, y\in\mathbb{R} \land y\neq0\bigg\} $$

Now I should calculate the corresponding Lie algebra....

Obviously, $G$ is a subgrouo of the general linear group $\mathrm{GL}_{2}(\mathbb{R})$.....But i have no idea how to construct the Lie algebra, which is the set of all left invariant vector fields.

Comment: The Lie algebra of $G$ consists of lower triangular matrices with zero trace.

Comment: Okay thank you.... But how do you get to this result?

Comment: Do you know at least that the Lie algebra of $G$ consists of matrices $A$ such that $e^A\in G$, where $e^A=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{A^k}{k!}$?  This should at least tell you that $A$ must be traceless.  It requires a little more work to show that $A$ is lower triangular.

Comment: Oh I see... Yeah makes sense.... Do you know how to proove that the matrices are lower trangle?

Comment: Let $G_0$ be the connected component containing the identity of $G$ (which consists of elements with $x>0$).  First show that the exponential map $\mathfrak{g}\to G_0$ is surjective, where $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Lie algebra of traceless lower triangular matrix.  Then injectivity is done by first considering the nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{g}$.  Show that they are mapped to different elements of $G$.  Then, using diagonalization for non-nilpotent elements of $\mathfrak{g}$, show that they are also mapped to different elements of $G$.

Comment: Adapt the answers to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3211833/96384 to your group. You don't really need the exponential map here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two parameters, so two generators, so one commutation relation. Has to be the [affine group in one dimension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra#Two_dimensions), here transposed.
$$
G= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    x  & 0  \\
    y  & 1/x 
\end{bmatrix}  
$$
goes to the identity for $x=1, y=0$. At the identity, then, you have $$
\partial G/\partial x  \to  \begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 0  \\
    0  &  -1 
\end{bmatrix} \equiv a ~, $$
and 
$$
\partial G/\partial y  \to  \begin{bmatrix}
    0  & 0  \\
    1  &  0 
\end{bmatrix} \equiv b ~, $$
so, then,
$$
[b,a]=2b .
$$

Exponentiating an arbitrary linear combination of these two Lie algebra elements yields the generic form *G* you started with, since the relevant [CBH expansion sums elegantly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula#Special_cases) to a simple closed form: your starting point.

Consider the wisecrack
$$
G= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    x  & 0  \\
    y  & 1/x 
\end{bmatrix} = 
 \begin{bmatrix}
    x  & 0  \\
    0  & 1/x 
\end{bmatrix}  
 \begin{bmatrix}
    1  & 0  \\
    y x  & 1 
\end{bmatrix} = e^{(\ln x) ~a}  e^{xy~ b}  ,
$$
and its CBH contraction,
$$
=\exp \left ( \ln x ~a -2xy\frac {\ln x}{1-x^2}   b   \right ) = e^{\omega(a + b y/\!\sinh \omega)},
$$
upon the definition $x\equiv e^\omega$.